# Absolute votes by political party

Tags: united-states, voter-turnout

I'm looking for data on the absolute votes received by each of the political parties (Democrat and Republican most importantly) over recent elections (since at least 2000) in the USA, including (estimates) for the current election.

In particular I'm trying to answer a query: *In past elections, democratic turnout has been a critical factor to the outcome, whereas republican turnout has been quite consistent from year to year, in terms of absolute numbers. With the record turnout this year I want to know to what degree this trend has held for the current election.*

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable.  Some states don't require people to register with a particular party, or allow "independent" as an option, and there's no central organization that people have to sign up with to be part of a party.  The best you're going to be able to do is approximate it based on combining the states that _do_ require party registration and polling questions about which party people lean towards.   Even then, it won't account for split-ticket voting.  Trump did worse than the GOP Representatives and Senators in a lot of races this year, for example.

Comment: If I understand the question, this would seem resolved by a comparison between 2016 and 2020. Republican votes increased by 8 million. Roughly inline with the increased turnout. So it is not the case Republican support is consistent and Democrat support fluctuates with turnout. Let me know if my understanding is correct and I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has this summarised

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_presidential_candidates_by_number_of_votes_received

```
Candidate       Year    Party       Popular vote    Notes
Joe Biden       2020    Democratic  ≥75,000,000     Winner; exact vote count pending
Donald Trump    2020    Republican  ≥70,500,000     Exact vote count pending
Jo Jorgensen    2020    Libertarian ≥1,700,000      Exact vote count pending
Howie Hawkins   2020    Green       ≥340,000        Exact vote count pending
Hillary Clinton 2016    Democratic  65,853,514[3]   Received the most votes, but lost the electoral college.
Donald Trump    2016    Republican  62,984,828[3]   Winner. Lost the popular vote, but won the electoral college.
Gary Johnson    2016    Libertarian 4,489,235[3]    
Jill Stein      2016    Green       1,457,226[3]    
Evan McMullin   2016    Independent 732,273[3]  
Darrell Castle  2016    Constitution203,091[3]  
Barack Obama    2012    Democratic  65,915,795[2]   Winner
Mitt Romney     2012    Republican  60,933,504[2]   
Gary Johnson    2012    Libertarian 1,275,971[2]    
Jill Stein      2012    Green       469,627[2]  
Barack Obama    2008    Democratic  69,498,516[1]   Winner
John McCain     2008    Republican  59,948,323[1]   
Ralph Nader     2008    Independent 739,034[1]  
Bob Barr        2008    Libertarian 523,715[1]  
Chuck Baldwin   2008    Constitution199,750[1]  
Cynthia McKinney2008    Green       161,797[1]  
George W. Bush  2004    Republican  62,040,610[4]   Winner
John Kerry      2004    Democratic  59,028,444[4]   
Ralph Nader     2004    Independent 465,151[4]      Also endorsed by the Reform Party
Michael Badnarik2004    Libertarian 397,265[4]  
Michael Peroutka2004    Constitution143,630[4]  
David Cobb      2004    Green       119,859[4]  
Al Gore         2000    Democratic  50,999,897[6]   Received the most votes, but lost the electoral college.
George W. Bush  2000    Republican  50,456,002[6]   Winner. Lost the popular vote, but won the electoral college.
Ralph Nader     2000    Green       2,882,955[6]    
Pat Buchanan    2000    Reform      448,895[6]  
Harry Browne    2000    Libertarian 384,431[6]
```

You may wish to cross reference this with turnout and VEP numbers
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_turnout_in_the_United_States_presidential_elections